# How to get SharePoint online site usage report using sp/pnp?

Tags: sharepoint, analysis, spfx, pnp-js

I have created SharePoint Framework Solution for custom development in the SharePoint Online.

I need to display SharePoint site usage report in my SPFx web part.

I have tried with @pnp/graph and @pnp/sp but I can not find any solution.

Can anyone help me with the same?

Thanks

Comment: would you please provide us with an update on the status of your issue?

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, PnP JS library does not support fetching SharePoint online site usage report currently.

You can have a look at the PnP JS library documentation and see if you can find anything relevant there: [PnP JS library documentation](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/)

**Similar thread**: [How to get SharePoint online site usage report using pnp/sp?](https://github.com/pnp/pnpjs/issues/2684)